# How to divide work unevenly between resources in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, resources

I'd like to divide a task between resources at different usage levels to get the shortest duration for the task.  For Example

Task A : 80 hrs work
Resource 1: 100%
Resource 2: 50%

I want this to result in something like 7 days duration: Resource 1 = 54 hours, Resource 2 = 26 hours

Instead...

MS project divides the work evenly between the two resources and completes the task based on the slowest (least utilized) resource: 10 day with 40 hours each for resource 1 and 2. Thus resource 1 stops working once they've done their 40 hours

[image: screen capture]

How do I get MS project to keep all resources working at their maximum rate until a task is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have defined the task as "Effort driven"? I think with that setting enabled, Project should calculate it based on the max. availability to finish the task as quick as possible.